If I see the same job advertised 1-4 months later, should I apply for it with the same resume?
I sometimes see the exact same job posting a few months later. I guess this happens because the previous hire didn't work out, or they're hiring another person for the exact same position. Is it OK to apply again with the same resume and cover letter? If I have an email address from correspondence (for example had already done an interview) can I contact them to let them know I would stile like to be considered?

Yes, but unless you got really, really close to getting hired last time around then you're probably going to get the same result (i.e. not getting hired) as Rita Mae Brown once wrote: ‘Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.’, so if your application didn't go anywhere last time just rinse-repeating isn't likely to get you anywhere either. So try and think why they didn't hire you last time, is there a way you address that with your resume or (more likely) cover letter? Experience that you possess that you didn't sufficiently highlight last time etc.
On the other hand if you got reasonably far through the process last time then it isn't a bad idea to get in touch with your prior contact and letting them know you've seen the advert and would still be interested if they were open to considering you. They may still have your details on file but you can always send it to them again easily enough.


Is it OK to apply again with the same resume and cover letter?

Yes.
If you have new skills, degrees, or certificates, you can also add them to your resume.
You can reapply for the position. They may be interested in interviewing you again if they think you are a good match.

However, please note that some companies want to wait for about 1 year before they would interview candidates that they reject. This is especially true for big tech companies (FAANG).


If I see the same job advertised 1-4 months later, should I apply for
it with the same resume?

There can be thousands of employees in one geographic area, which mean they can have the same location information, and the same description, but have an entirely different set of people making the hiring decision.
When deciding who I would interview the previous attempts would not make a difference unless the notes show that they should not ever be hired. The fact that you didn't make it through the process, or were the second choice has no relationship to meeting the qualifications for my team.
Of course if it is the exact same position, with the same team, and the same hiring staff, having applied recently may help your case or hurt your case.
I would freshen the resume based on a re-readng of the job listing. I would make a new cover letter. Use what you learned the last time you applied to make these documents better for this application.
Applying again doesn't hurt.

Yes. It's fine to do so.
If you have rewritten the resume since then and like the new version, you can send that instead. Your choice.
It can't hurt to reapply; at most you waste a bit of paper and postage.


Is it OK to apply again with the same resume and cover letter?

Of course it's okay.
But if it didn't work last time, it probably makes sense to at least change something - likely the cover letter.

This sounds like a phishing for resume scam to me. There very well may not be a real job and it is just some sort of staff solution company phishing for resumes to sell to employers
